# Correct format for Node architecture (BASIC)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller, module

**Introduction**

I have built some back end functionality in Node (First time using Node). Problem is that the whole thing was built in one page (index.js) so now im following a few basic tutorials and setting out express router middleware and now trying to follow a modular MVC approach,

This code is simple but brakes when I separate into two pages `Server.js` and `config.js`. I know its a simple problem but i cant spot it. can someone help spot the problem and maybe improve the structure ?

**Problem**

I go to `http://localhost:8080/about` or a different route and I get

> Cannot GET /about

rather than the correct print out.

**back-end/server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var port    =   process.env.PORT || 8080;

// get an instance of router
var router = express.Router();

// START THE SERVER
// ==============================================
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server has started!! ' + port);
```

**back-end/config.js**

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {

    console.log(req.method, req.url);

    next();
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('im the home page!');
});

// sample route with a route the way we're used to seeing it
router.get('/sample', function(req, res) {
    res.send('this is a sample!');
});


router.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    res.send('im the about page!');
});


app.route('/login')

    .get(function(req, res) {
        res.send('this is the login form');
    })

    .post(function(req, res) {
        console.log('processing'); // shows on console when post is made
        res.send('processing the login form!'); // output on postman
    });

app.use('/', router);
```

Comment: You're never actually running the second file.

Comment: How would I run the second file, do i include in the first ? like `include('back-end/config.js');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SLaks said in his comment, you need to import (`require`) your `backend/config.js` file. But it's not as simple as that...

In node, variables are scoped to the file in which they appear, so if you simply add `require('./config')` to your `server.js` file, that's not going to work either, because the `router` variable in `config.js` is local to that file - it's not going to know about the `router` variable in `server.js`.

The solution to this is to have the `config.js` file export a function which the `server.js` file can use to configure stuff. For example

**config.js**

```
module.exports = function(router) {

    // set up your router here with router.use, etc.

};
```

**server.js**

```
var configure = require('./config');

// after you set up your express router...
configure(router);

// now start listening
```